# Representing in data table format in react native

Tags: json, api, react-native, datatable

I am new to **react-native**
I am want to show data in **.json** format in **data table** format.
Mentioned below is the link for .json file
https://api.covidindiatracker.com/state_data.json
I am able to fetch using API.
But how to **convert** it into a **data table**
[Ths is what I am able to do](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7GGZv.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are using **native base**, why are you not using the card component?
https://docs.nativebase.io/Components.html#card-def-headref

because `table` are hard to display on mobile.